# Algorithm for finding continuous repeated sequences

Tags: string, algorithm, sequence

I'm looking for an algorithm that finds short tandem repeats in a genome sequence.

Basically, given a really long string which can only consist of the 4 characters 'ATCG', I need to find short repeats between 2-5 characters long that are next to each other.

ex:
TACATGAGATCATGATGATGATGATGGAGCTGTGAGATC
would give   *ATGATGATG* or ATG repeated 3 times

The algorithm needs to scale up to a string of 1 million characters so I'm trying to get as close to linear runtime as possible.

My current algorithm:
Since the repeats can be 2-5 characters long, I check the string character by character and see if the Nth character is the same as the N+Xth character, with X being 2 through 5. With a counter for each X that counts sequential matches and resets at a mismatch, we know if there is a repeat when X = the counter. The subsequent repeats can then be checked manually.

Comment: What is the problem with your current algorithm?

Comment: Seems like your current algorithm is already O(n) if X is bounded

Comment: The algorithm itself sounds feasible. If performance is an issue, your should definitely consider (high-level: ) parallelizing it (should be embarassingly parallel), and possibly (low-level: ) keep in mind language-specific performance implications, like that of `String` objects vs. `char[]` arrays, for example

Comment: How fast has it to be? I achieved more than 50 MiB/s with a single thread and the most straight forward implementation on my laptop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking at each character which gives you `O(n)`, since you compare on each character the next (*maximum*) five characters this gives you a constant `c`:

```
var data    = get_input();
var compare = { `A`, `T`, `G`, `A`, `T` }         // or whatever
var MAX_LOOKAHEAD = compare.length
var n
var c

for(n = data_array.length; n < size; i++) {       // Has runtime O(n)

  for(c = 0; c < MAX_LOOKAHEAD; c++) {            // Maximum O(c)

    if( compare[c] != data[i+c] ) {
      break;
    } else {
      report( "found match at position " + i )
    }

  }
}
```

It is easy to see that this runs `O(n*c)` times. Since `c` is very small it can be ignored - and I think one can not get rid of that constant - which results in a total runtime of `O(n)`.

**The good news:**

You can speed this up with parallelization. E.g. you could split this up in `k` intervals and let multiple threads do the job for you by giving them appropriate start and end indices. This could give you a *linear speedup*.

If you do that make sure that you treat the intersections as special cases since you could miss a match if your intervals split a match in two.

E.g. `n = 50000`:

Partition for 4 threads: `(n/10000) - 1 = 4`. The 5th thread won't have a lot to do since it just handles the intersections which is why we don't need to consider its (*in our case tiny*) overhead.

```
1                 10000               20000               40000               50000
|-------------------|-------------------|-------------------|-------------------|
| <-   thread 1  -> | <-   thread 2  -> | <-   thread 3  -> | <-   thread 4  -> |
                  |---|               |---|               |---|              
                    |___________________|___________________|
                                        |
                                     thread 5
```

And this is how it could look like:

```
var data;
var compare = { `A`, `T`, `G`, `A`, `T` };
var MAX_LOOKAHEAD = compare.length;

thread_function(args[]) {

    var from = args[0];
    var to   = args[1];

    for(n = from ; n < to ; i++) {

      for(c = 0; c < MAX_LOOKAHEAD; c++) {
        if( compare[c] != data[i+c] ) {
          break;
        } else {
          report( "found match at position " + i )
        }
      }
    }
}

main() {
    var data_size     = 50000;
    var thread_count  = 4;
    var interval_size = data_size / ( thread_count + 1) ;

    var tid[]

    // This loop starts the threads for us:

    for( var i = 0; i < thread_count; i++ ) {
        var args = { interval_size * i, (interval_size * i) + interval_size };

        tid.add( create_thread( thread_function, args ) );
    }

    // And this handles the intersections:

    for( var i = 1; i < thread_count - 1; i++ ) {
        var args = { interval_size * i, (interval_size * i) + interval_size };

        from = (interval_size * i) - compare.length + 1;
        to   = (interval_size * i) + compare.length - 1;

        for(j = from; j < to ; j++) {

            for(k = 0; k < MAX_LOOKAHEAD; k++) {
                if( compare[k] != data[j+k] ) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    report( "found match at position " + j )
                }
            }
        }
    }

    wait_for_multiple_threads( tid );
}
```