# Ignoring Repeated Sets of Logging

Tags: c++, algorithm, logging

There is a program that is logging a lot of information, some of which tends to repeat itself in certain situations. I've been tasked with preventing this over-logging and I need some direction as to what to do. Currently I can prevent the same message in a row from repeating, but it becomes a lot more tricky when preventing various sized unique sets of log messages from occurring.

I tried to first break down the problem into a smaller one by which I am using characters to represent unique log messages.

**Input**

```
aaaaababababacdefgfggfabcddggddgg
```

**Output**

```
abacdefgfabcdg
0 : Hash: 100, Msg: d
1 : Hash: 103, Msg: g
```

This is the output for my current program which seems to work for 1-2 unique characters. All the characters displayed in a row represent the messages that are logged and the next two lines show what my current buffer used to compare sequences contains. Therefore if I were to add "xz" to the original input I get the following output

```
abacdefgfabcdgdg
0 : Hash: 120, Msg: x
1 : Hash: 122, Msg: z
```

As we can see the `d`, `g` get "logged" and the next sequence we don't allow to occur would be 'xz' or 'z' based on what's in the sequence buffer.

**Does anyone know of an actual algorithm that can detect/prevent repeated unique sequences?**

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23574738/algorithm-for-finding-continuous-repeated-sequences) but it doesn't quite fit my needs.

More Examples

> Input -> Desired Output
>
> 1. ABCABCACD -> ABCACD
> 2. AAABABACBCBCB -> ABACB
> 3. ABBABBA -> ABABA
> 4. ACDACDDDCDC -> ACDC

The letters represent unique log messages and I'd like to prevent the repeated sets of log messages from showing up.

Comment: What is the size of the problem? I.e. give us a rough estimate of how many log messages/sec. Do you want the messages to be unique for the entire log? That could be hard with a large log. One way to restrict problem size would be to process the log in blocks, and only guarantee that a message is unique within its own block.

Comment: This sounds bad. There is already alot of overhead in logging, why would you want to make it worse by tracking logged messages in the process that logs them? Why would you only want to see that first message? It looks like what you really need is a mainstream logger that provides filtering and/or to reevaluate how and what you are logging. If this is for some real world production project, I'd surely raise an eyebrow. Not enough context is provided to really suggest anything.

Comment: Look up compression algorithms.  You are compressing the output (logging) stream.

Comment: Do you need to log date or time stamps?

Comment: The problem I would like to solve is the logs can, if the application is in a broken state, fill the logs with repeated sequence of messages. And so troubleshooting becomes impossible because the useful log messages have since been overwritten @ChristopherPisz

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Yeah we currently log the date and time, I would filter before, but keep the first timestamp occurrence of the message.

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz Then get your QA guy to come up with the steps to reproduce, identify the repeating messages, and put a filter on them, and then run the scenario. Trying to implement an entire permanent system and add long term overhead, for this one scenario, doesn't seem wise, imo. At any rate, you'd just hash the whole message or the identifying part, and see if it exists in your hash before writing it out. It would be really expensive.

Comment: @HostileFork the examples are ones where the left hand side is input, and the right hand side is the expected correct output.

Comment: Rather than compression, consider using a filter.  Design your system so that you can supply one or more filters.  A configuration file could help specify these filters (similar to Window's Open File dialog box).  If a logging text matches a filter, output date and time and a simple output, like "removed via filter".

Comment: Yeah that's what I am doing, I am going to filter the log messages based on the repeating sequences while the messages are being logged and prevent them from being logged if they are part of the repeating sequence. @ThomasMatthews

Comment: I think I know what algorithm you are using but the way it is being described isn't clear so the test cases are inconsistent.  If AAABABACBCBCB would be AAABABACBCBCB->ABABACBCBCB->ABACBCBCB->ABACBCB->ABACB then ABBABBA would be ABBABBA->ABABBA->ABBA or it could be ABBABBA->ABBA but I don't see how you could get ABABA

Comment: ABBABBA -> ABABA because it's not allowed to have a message outputted twice or more in a row @JerryJeremiah

Comment: you have to think of the input as a stream which doesn't stop @JerryJeremiah

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get what you're trying to do here.  You're trying to eliminate "repeated sequences" but then you're having a sequence show up more than once in the output (e.g. `ABBABBA -> ABABA` repeating AB on the right).  If AB can appear twice in the output (and hence isn't a "repeated sequence" you want removed) then where does this stop?  Why aren't you considering the whole of `ABBABBA` a non-repeated sequence--it only happens once!  *You need to formally define the problem in very clear terms at the top of your question.*

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz  if you remove any repeated occurence of single characters before moving to multiple characters then ABBABBA->ABABA and then ACDACDDDCDC->ACDACDCDC->ACDCDC->ACDC or ACDACDDDCDC->ACDACDCDC->ACDACDC->ACDC